# LocalThread with AOP with Spring

Tags: multithreading, spring-aop

I am using LocalThread, which is register with Aop

```
class A {
    public static final ThreadLocal<Instance> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<Instance>();
}
```

class B{

```
  @Before("target()")
    public void init() throws Throwable {

        if (CONTEXT.get() == null) {
            Instance i = new Instance(1)
            SFTP_CLIENT_CONTEXT.set(i);

        } 

    }

    @After("target()")
     public void destroy() throws Throwable {
      CONTEXT.get().getValue();
            ThreadLocalManager.CONTEXT.remove();


    }
 }
```

Is it good idea to register local thread with aop,
Also i am under **sometime** i get nullpointer exp in After notation

```
CONTEXT.get().getValue();
```

I know it's mean there in no data present in local thread, but i am wondering how it's possible because i have set it on @Before

(Basically this exception is coming when **multiple thread** processed my service method (pointcut defined for it)  )

Comment: Your question is a bit incoherent, unfortunately. It would be more helpful to edit your question and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. something I can actually compile and run, to make your problem reproduceable. Then I am sure you have a better chance of getting good answers.